# how do i unbind mouse over event on daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

I am using **daterangepicker** , when mouseover on calendar date is changing on text box. But i want to hide this functionality.

How do i unbind mouse over event ?  or give me any other ideas

**note:**
daterangepicker url
http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do one thing.
First go to calendar.
Right click on your browser and click on InspectElement.
Find the onmouseover event and delete that calling function.

or

Disable javascript.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . i will do that.

Comment: i have done myself.. i have modified hoverDate function on daterangepicker js library